# git-svn produces different hashes on windows and osx

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I've got a bit of a messy situation. My company uses svn, but I develop locally using git-svn on my Windows and OSX computers. I'm trying to allow the Windows machine to push and pull from the OSX laptop, and I hit the "No common commits" when pulling the OSX local branch. **The basic facts are**:

- Both Windows and OSX have a git-svn repo tracking SVN trunk
- Both repos are up-to-date and show rev 10 as the newest log message
- `git log` shows the message as the same, with the same author hash, but the commit hash is different

This is what's causing the "No common commits" problem, but why are the hashes different? If it's a line-ending problem, or a case-sensitive filename problem, how can I make git find me the differences.

Note: This is a giant (1.8GB) repo, so I likely can't manually fix or compare files.

Comment: Are all commit hashes different, or just the latest? You can run `git rev-list` in both repos to get a list of commit hashes.

Comment: I'm guessing all are different from the "no common commits" bit. Try `git cat-file -p $SHA` with the sha of the *first* commit (the one with no parents). Is the only difference the tree? If it is, you can use `git ls-tree -r $SHA` to get the hash of every entry in the tree, and you can compare that in both repos to see what's different.

Comment: Kevin, these two repositories have different svn revisions as their first commits. That means that, if Win starts @5, and OSX starts @10, Win@10 will have a parent, and OSX@10 won't, so that'll throw off the hash, and ruin everything downstream. That's likely the problem. Git's inherent resistance to tampering means I can't just delete the earlier history from Win so that it also starts at 10. I have to re-check out, right?

Comment: If they started at different revisions, that is *definitely* the issue. Both repos need to start at the same revision, and use the same configuration (e.g. same authors file, if any, same understanding of what trunk, branches, tags, are, etc). You actually can muck with the history if you want. Simplest way is probably to set up a [graft](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/articles/g/r/a/GraftPoint_2c06.html) that declares that Win@10 has no parent, and then use git-filter-branch to "bake" that. This *should* produce a Win@10 that's identical to your OSX@10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kevin pointed out some investigation tools, and I realized my svn branches started tracking at different svn revisions. This is the cause of the problem, and I just re-downloaded the repository rather than try and figure out how to graft a branch onto another one (waste computer time overnight rather than my brain time during the day). Thanks Kevin